# BizTalk 2016 and Windows SharePoint Services troubleshooting

Tags: biztalk, sharepoint-online, biztalk-2016

I am supposed to update SharePoint list with information from BizTalk 2016. I am aiming at using Windows SharePoint Services adapter and CSOM. I have enabled Windows Identity Foundation (after installing BizTalk) on the BizTalk server.

I get the following error when send port runs:

> The Windows SharePoint Services site was not found. The URL
>   "http://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/yyy/" points to a
>   SharePoint object for which there is no Windows SharePoint Services
>   site.

I have enabled tracing of WIF (but I get no logs):

```
<system.diagnostics>  
 <sources>  
  <source name="System.IdentityModel" switchValue="Verbose">  
   <listeners>  
    <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\logs\WIF.xml" />  
   </listeners>  
  </source>  
 </sources>  
 <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

I have tried both supplying credentials in send port configuration, and by running specific host with specific domain account. Same error.

Windows Firewall is disable on the BizTalk machine.

Comment: Have you tried using another tool such as Postman or SoapUI to try to connect to the SharePoint site?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, I connected with same url + credentials via web browser, using email-style username of domain account. I was able to see the list. I only get the above error message when run from BizTalk. like WIF never gets activated...(and no tracing is done).

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, I have now tested to run ARC and get following error back:

X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.

Comment: Is it possible the error message is misleading and you don't have permission in sharepoint under the biztalk service account?

Comment: @Jay, Of Course, the error message is misleading! ;) I have come up with an answer to this problem (see below). Now on to the next misleading error message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My scenario was that customer recently asked for the update to sharepoint online list. So, I needed to activate WIF AFTER BizTalk installation. In my trials to solve this I also installed latest CU6 and did a repair on the installation, too. But same problem.

I got a powershell script to use to test connectivity and verify SharePoint online list's accessability, to exclude the adapter itself and limit the scope of the problem. Running the script, there was a problem finding classes in the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll assembly. Apparently, something was missing on the machine!

I installed SharePoint Client SDK on the machine, and - eureka - i got to the next error message!

Seems like you do need to install additional assemblies to Windows SharePoint Services Adapter, even though the documentation says otherwise. Possibly, this is due to activating WIF AFTER BizTalk installation.

On to the next (misleading) error message!